# Having trouble with using RecyclerView with Parse database inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I'm very new to Android programming and I'm trying to connect a Parse Database to my RecyclerView. When I open this fragment it closes the entire app in failure. It was working before when my event object only had one parameter and I queried one section of the database but I had to change it to a separate object because I needed more sections of the database. I also tried moving the RecyclerView in different sections in and out of the Query methods but it still does not open and because it was working before I'm sure my problem lies in the EventFragment class.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 *
 */

public class EventFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    TextView text;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static adapter adapt;

    public static List<Event> dbObjects = Collections.emptyList();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Log.d("IN EVENT FRAGMENT", "WE ARE IN!!!!");

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
        query.whereExists("title");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objList, ParseException e) {
                //dbObjects = scoreList;
                //adapt = new adapter(getActivity(), dbObjects);
                if (e == null) {

                    for (ParseObject obj : objList) {
                        //Log.d("DEBUG", "The username is:" + dbObjects.size());

                        Event event = new Event(obj.getString("title"), obj.getString("eventDate"));


                        dbObjects.add(event);
                    }



                } else {
                    Log.d("HELLO", "Something went wrong!");
                }


            }
        });

        //RecyclerView
        adapt = new adapter(getActivity(), dbObjects);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);


        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public static List<Event> data;

    public adapter(Context context, List<Event> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = objects;
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;

    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Event current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(current.getDate());
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView date;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }
    }

}
```

And my event object

```
public class Event {
    public String title;
    public String date;

    public Event(String tit, String dat) {
        title = tit;
        date = dat;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
09-10 09:10:02.116    6767-6767/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-10 09:10:03.231    6767-6779/suyash.sjsu_cs_club I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1793(132KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 35MB/35MB, paused 3.498ms total 116.782ms
09-10 09:10:03.241    6767-6779/suyash.sjsu_cs_club W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.643ms
09-10 09:10:03.452    6767-6779/suyash.sjsu_cs_club W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.751ms
09-10 09:10:03.922    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
09-10 09:10:03.928    6767-6767/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0b8e70, tid 6767
09-10 09:10:03.953    6767-6767/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
09-10 09:10:04.041    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c91360, tid 6790
09-10 09:10:04.069    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-10 09:10:04.188    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-10 09:10:04.205    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-10 09:10:04.205    6767-6790/suyash.sjsu_cs_club W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cab0c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-10 09:10:21.407    6767-6767/suyash.sjsu_cs_club D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-10 09:10:21.408    6767-6767/suyash.sjsu_cs_club E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: suyash.sjsu_cs_club, PID: 6767
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
            at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
            at suyash.sjsu_cs_club.EventFragment$1.done(EventFragment.java:66)
            at suyash.sjsu_cs_club.EventFragment$1.done(EventFragment.java:54)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
09-10 09:11:52.915    6767-6774/suyash.sjsu_cs_club W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.668ms
```

Also this is a separate question that probably needs a second post but how would I create an onItemClickListener for a RecyclerView whose contents regularly change in the Database?

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
public static List<Event> dbObjects = Collections.emptyList();
```

If you change it to

```
public static List<Event> dbObjects = new LinkedList<Event>();
```

it will work.

Why? Because `Collections.emptyList()` returns `EmptyList` which is a custom implemention of `AbstractList` which does nothing.

Here is how `EmptyView` class looks like.

```
private static final class EmptyList extends AbstractList
        implements RandomAccess, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8842843931221139166L;

    @Override public boolean contains(Object object) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override public int size() {
        return 0; 
    }

    @Override public Object get(int location) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override public Iterator iterator() {
        return EMPTY_ITERATOR;
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

And here is the snippet of `add()` methods in `AbstractList`.

```
@Override
public boolean add(E object) {
    add(size(), object);
    return true;
}    

public void add(int location, E object) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```